# wordpress function breaks wp-admin

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

I've created a function in my custom WooCommerce site. This works great on the frontend, but wp-admin breaks. Wp-admin shows a http-500 error.

This is the function:

```
// Set currency based on visitor country
 
function geo_client_currency($client_currency) {
        $country = WC()->customer->get_shipping_country();
           switch ($country) {
            case 'GB': return 'GBP'; break;
            default: return 'EUR'; break;
        }
}
add_filter('wcml_client_currency','geo_client_currency');
```

I've set the `wp-debug` on true and it will throw this message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_shipping_country() on null in

So it has to do something with: `$country = WC()->customer->get_shipping_country();` but I can't find it. What is my mistake?

Comment: `WC()` doesn't return anything, that has a property `customer`.

Comment: That make sense. But how to edit this function so it works on the frontend as well as the backend?

Comment: As it is a PHP function you will run into problems getting it to work on the frontend. What does that `WC()` function actually return?

Comment: I need the shipping country value in WooCommerce to know which currency have to be displayed in the shop. The English language doesn't mean, the currency have to be Pounds. It depands on the browser language. So only for visitors in the UK will see the Pound currency. the rest of Europe the EURO.

Comment: This is the reason for you hook there. But I can't find a plain `WC()` function in the woocommerce docu - so I'm asking just about, what that function returns.

Comment: The customers shipping-country in the checkout field

Comment: As said above, `WC()->customer` doesn't exist in the admin. Maybe you should use some conditional logic to only apply this filter in the frontend?

Answer (score 0):

The `customer` property isn't set to an instance of `WC_Customer` in the backend so you can't call the `get_shipping_country()` method.

Check `customer` isn't null (default) before using it.

```
function geo_client_currency( $client_currency ) {
    if ( WC()->customer ) {
        $country = WC()->customer->get_shipping_country();

        /**
         * Assuming more are going to be added otherwise a switch is overkill.
         * Short example: $client_currency = ( 'GB' === $country ) ? 'GBP' : 'EUR';
         */
        switch ( $country ) {
            case 'GB': 
                $client_currency = 'GBP'; 
                break;

            default: 
                $client_currency = 'EUR';
        }
    }

    return $client_currency;
}
add_filter( 'wcml_client_currency', 'geo_client_currency' );
```